# How much is a 10 day trip ticket Rahway to Penn Station

Tags: new-york-city, new-jersey

How much is a 10 day trip ticket Rahway to Penn Station? I saw that there are 10 trip one way tickets so I guess you get a good discount.

Actually I have to travel from Rahway to Penn Station and then take subway near Wellington hotel station. This is because hotels are terrible expensive and have to stay 10 days in NY so I want to see how much I can save by staying in a hotel near Rahway station in New Jersey.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Prices change so often that price shopping is, unfortunately, off topic on this site.  You can certainly ask generalities about whether certain types of travel are more cost-effective than others, because those answers tend to remain valid for a long time.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate some initial research effort; it is not difficult to find this information on https://www.njtransit.com/ on your own, so it isn't clear why you would need our help. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2):

A trip is a one-way ride, so assuming you make 2 trips a day over the 10 days, you'll be taking 20 trips.

From filling out the schedule request for NYPenn and Rahway on [NJTransit's website](https://www.njtransit.com/sf/sf_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TrainTo):

[image]

There doesn't appear to be any particular discount for a Ten Trip ticket, since the regular one way fare is $9.25, and the Ten Trip is $92.50. The Ten Trip seems to be geared towards people who occasionally need to travel the route and can save time by buying multiple trips with one purchase.

A combination of a Weekly pass ($82.50) and a set of one way tickets (6? x $9.25) to cover the remaining days might be a better deal if one needs to travel regularly for a short period of time. ($82.50 + $55.50 = $138)

From [NJ Transit website - Ticket Options](https://www.njtransit.com/ti/ti_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=RailTicketsTo)

> **Weekly Passes**
>   Unlimited trips between two rail stations from 12:01 a.m. Saturday through 6:00 a.m. on the following Saturday. On sale beginning Thursday and continuing through Tuesday. Rail weekly passes can also be used on light rail or bus.

The following is just an example of scheduled trains for this morning. The Rahway - NY Penn track is covered by two lines, North Jersey Coast and Northeast Corridor.

[image]

Just a caveat on buying tickets. There may be an extra charge if you don't get the ticket prior to boarding the train. (Bolding emphasis mine.)

> **Ticket Purchases On-Board Trains**
>   You can purchase tickets aboard the train without penalty only if there is no ticket agent or ticket
>   vending machine available (**A $5 surcharge is applied to tickets
>   purchased aboard trains if a ticket agent or ticket vending machine is
>   available at time of boarding**). Customers with disabilities and senior
>   citizens (62 or older) may purchase tickets aboard any train without
>   penalty. Conductors cannot accept bills larger than $20.

**Note**:
Fares are current as of August 2018. Fares may increase in 2019 depending on state budget negotiations. [NJ.com article](https://www.nj.com/traffic/index.ssf/2018/06/is_an_nj_transit_fare_hike_coming_murphy_wont_rule.html)

Comment: How did you get that rate of 5 USD? I just went to the website and select Rahway to New York Penn Station and the rate is 9..25?

Comment: Your 9.25 is correct - I'm sorry, I picked the wrong Penn Station initially. There's a Penn Station in both Newark and New York. They can sound similar when being announced on the train too. So if you're on the way from Rahway to NY Penn, make sure you don't get off the train early at Newark Penn.